# Schedule notification using flutter_local_notifications

Tags: flutter, dart, push-notification, dart-pub

I'm using `flutter_local_notifications` plug-in to send notifications to my users. But I need to schedule the notifications. So I use `zonedSchedule()` to do that.
The problem is that `zonedSchedule()` requires TZDateTime, so I need to convert DateTime to TZDateTime. I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64305469/how-to-convert-datetime-to-tzdatetime-in-flutter?answertab=active#tab-top) question, but it didn't work for me. I just need to get the `Location` of the user and pass to `TZDateTime.from(dateTime,location)`. How can I get this location?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just asked this question but I have the answer already. For those having trouble with the `Location`, you can just use `tz.getLocation(await FlutterNativeTimezone.getLocalTimezone())` to get the `location` parameter for `TZDateTime.from(dateTime,location)`.

PS.: Remember to import: `import 'package:timezone/data/latest.dart' as tz;` and
`import 'package:timezone/timezone.dart' as tz;`.

Also, you have to inicialize `tz`:

```
tz.initializeTimeZones();
tz.setLocalLocation(tz.getLocation(await FlutterNativeTimezone.getLocalTimezone()));
```

That's it, I hope it's useful.

Comment: This is also written in the documentation for flutter_local_notifications