# How to convert "MM/DD/YYYY" to TZDateTime format

Tags: flutter, timezone, flutter-local-notification

I am implementing flutter local notification plugin in my todo app and I want to schedule the
notification for a specific day and time, The date picker and time picker shows the date like this: **12/26/2021** and the time like this: **03:17 PM**, How do I convert this to TZDateTime format

Comment: See [How do I convert a date/time string to a DateTime object in Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49385303/) for how to parse a `String` to a `DateTime` object.  From there ,use [`TZDateTime.from`](https://pub.dev/documentation/timezone/latest/timezone.standalone/TZDateTime/TZDateTime.from.html) to convert a `DateTime` to a `TZDateTime`.

Comment: While converting from dateTime to TZDateTime it asks for location, what should I specify as location.

Comment: I can't answer that for you.You're the one who wants to use a `TZDateTime` object, which means that you want a version of `DateTime` that uses a specific time zone that isn't UTC and that isn't the local time.  You haven't indicated what time zone you want.  If you care only about local or UTC times, then you can just use a normal `DateTime` object (or, if you really need a `TZDateTime` object, use the `TZDateTime.utc` or `TZDateTime.local` constructors).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try out the below code

```
 TZDateTime tzDateTime;
    String dateTime = getFormattedDateFromFormattedString(
        value: "12/26/2021 3:16 PM",
        currentFormat: "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a",
        desiredFormat: "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

    tz.initializeTimeZones();
    tzDateTime = tz.TZDateTime.parse(tz.local, dateTime);

    print(tzDateTime);
}

// format your given time
  getFormattedDateFromFormattedString(
      {value, String currentFormat, String desiredFormat, isUtc = true}) {
    DateTime dateTime = DateTime.now();
    if (value != null || value.isNotEmpty) {
      try {
        dateTime = DateFormat(currentFormat).parse(value, isUtc).toLocal();
      } catch (e) {
        print("$e");
      }
    }
    return dateTime.toString();
  }
```

Comment: I get the error: _TypeError (type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'TZDateTime')

Comment: I think you miss something, please check out [dartpad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/?id=a2dc80fdac4b7fd5b098b48dbd7afbf9)

Comment: This returns a string but it should be in TZDateTime, So I tried TZDateTime.parse method, it asks for location, what should I do for location

Comment: i hope it will help you, please check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64305469/how-to-convert-datetime-to-tzdatetime-in-flutter)

Comment: RohithNambiar Check my answer

Comment: I tried tz.local but the notification never appears

Comment: updated my answer please check

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked after I changed isUTC to false

Answer (score 3):

import timezone

```
import 'package:timezone/data/latest_all.dart' as tz;
import 'package:timezone/timezone.dart' as tz;


tz.initializeTimeZones();
tz.TZDateTime.parse(tz.local, "2012-12-26 03:17:00");
//tz.UTC
```

Or

```
tz.TZDateTime.from(DateTime(2021,12,26,03,07), tz.local);
//tz.UTC
```

Comment: How do I convert 3:40 PM to 03:17:00 format

Comment: what is the type of 3:40PM  string or datetime?

Comment: Both the Date and time are String

Comment: Check this code [link](https://pastebin.com/qEQ4VBdS)